# Meteor.call with await/promise doesn't seem to synchronous

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been trying to call `meteor.call` in synchronous way. I tried to follow the example given in the [meteor forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/execute-code-once-the-meteor-callback-has-run/25905/4) doesn't seem to work.

```
const callWithPromise = (method, myParameters) => {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     Meteor.call(method, myParameters, (err, res) => {
     if (err) reject('Something went wrong');
        resolve(res);
     });
  });
 }
```

The following function diiidn't wait for the above and `doStuff()` returned immediateley after call.

```
async function doStuff() {
    const myValue1 = await callWithPromise('myMethod1', someParameters);
    const myValue2 = await callWithPromise('myMethod2', myValue1);
}
```

Any Input in the above is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*returned immediateley after call*"? It immediately returned a promise, right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `await` doesn't exactly do what you might expect (or want). And then it needs to be contained in an `async` function to be used :( It is still dealing with promises, and you need to be aware of that.

Meteor does, however, provide a Promise implementation that allows one to wait without needing to be inside an async function.

```
import { Promise } from 'meteor/promise'
```

and in your code you can do this:

```
const result = Promise.await(Metor.call('server-method',params))
```

`result` then contains whatever was returned by the Meteor method, so it behaves like a regular function call.

Answer (score 1):

As Bergi already pointed out, even an async function will return right away -- as the name suggests! -- even if inside of it you are allowed to await things. So you'll need to await on the async function, too. Here is a simplified example:

```
const wait = () => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); }
async function doit() { await wait(); console.log('waited'); }
doit(); console.log('the end');
```

will result in:

```
the end
waited
```

however:

```
await doit(); console.log('the end');
```

will do what you seem to want, namely:

```
waited
the end
```